# Finding my own comments on questions and answers

Tags: support, questions, comments, search

I don't know how to find the questions I've commented on.
Is there a search trick or some page that lists the comments I've posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see your recent comments by clicking [your profile (any username link)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139597/benny), then clicking on the [Activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139597?tab=activity#sort-top) tab.

This only keeps so many entries; I don't think there's any direct way to search for comments on questions you neither asked nor answered.

Comment: Damn, 32 seconds.

Comment: put in more links next time, it makes you faster... :)

Comment: Is there a way to search within my Posts / Comments and not just browse them?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your profile and click on the [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60777?tab=activity#sort-top) tab. It'll show you your recent comments so you can go back to them.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you can remember a bit of the phrasing in the comment. The best way to find a *particular* question/comment is probably to Google your user name and that phrase:

http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:stackoverflow.com+-site:meta.stackoverflow.com+%22josh+caswell%22+they+simply+haven%27t+rewritten

Comment: Is there a way to search within my Posts / Comments and not just browse them?